# Have problem of saving the model c# with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

There is a problem when saving the model. Here are my related models.

Mark:

```
public class Mark
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Марка")]
        public string MarkName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<CarModel> CarModels { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }

        public Mark()
        {
            CarModels = new List<CarModel>();
            Cars = new List<Car>();
        }
    }
```

CarModel:

```
public class CarModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Модель")]
        public string ModelName { get; set; }

        public int MarkId { get; set; }
        public virtual Mark Mark { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Equipment> Equipments { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }

        public CarModel()
        {
            Equipments = new List<Equipment>();
            Cars = new List<Car>();
        }
    }
```

Equipment:

```
public class Equipment
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Engine { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Power { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int ReleaseYear { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string DriveType { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Transmission { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Body { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int MaxSpeed { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Weight { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int MaxFuelVolume { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Color { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Picture { get; set; }

        public int CarModelId { get; set; }
        public virtual CarModel CarModel { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }

        public Equipment()
        {
            Cars = new List<Car>();
        }
    }
```

Car:

```
public class Car
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Price { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Count { get; set; }

        public int? MarkId { get; set; }
        public virtual Mark Mark { get; set; }

        public int CarModelId { get; set; }
        public virtual CarModel CarModel { get; set; }

        public int? EquipmentId { get; set; }
        public virtual Equipment Equipment { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }

        public Car()
        {
            Orders = new List<Order>();
        }
    }
```

So, if I add a new car and at the same time a new brand, model and package bundle, the storage goes well, the brand is created, the model is tied to it, the model is bundled with the model, and below is the essence of the car with references to all this.

Here is the code for an example:

```
Context db = new Context();

Equipment equip = new Equipment() 
                      { Body = "Седан", Color = "Красный", DriveType = "Передний", Engine = 1600,
                        MaxFuelVolume = 60, MaxSpeed = 250, Picture = "Картинка", Power = 150,
                        ReleaseYear = 2015, Transmission = "Автомат", Weight = 2000 };
Mark mark = new Mark() { MarkName = "BMW" };
CarModel carModel = new CarModel() { ModelName = "M3" };

Car car = new Car();
car.Mark = mark;
car.CarModel = carModel;
car.Equipment = equip;

unitOfWOrk.Cars.Create(car);
unitOfWOrk.Save();
```

But if I try to create a car and link an existing make and an existing model to it, but a new complete set will fail

> An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

Here is the example code:

```
Context db = new Context();
Equipment equip = new Equipment() { Body = "Седан", Color = "Красный", DriveType = "Передний", Engine = 1600,
                                    MaxFuelVolume = 60, MaxSpeed = 250, Picture = "Картинка", Power = 150,
                                    ReleaseYear = 2015, Transmission = "Автомат", Weight = 2000 };

Car car = new Car();
car.MarkId = 1;
car.CarModelId = 1;
car.Equipment = equip;
```

As I understand it swears at `public int CarModelId {get; set; }` in the `Equipment` model, because I tried to do an `int?` and then this error is not. So the question is why, when creating new data, an entity guesses what to bind to, and in the case of adding new data, this does not happen

InnerException:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Equipments_dbo.CarModels_CarModelId". The conflict occurred in database "D:\AUTOSTORE\AUTOSTORE\APP_DATA\AUTOSTOREDB.MDF", table "dbo.CarModels", column 'Id'. The statement has been terminated.

Comment: what does innerException says?

Comment: @Simonare Wrote an internal error in the question.

Comment: does their exist a CarModel with Id 1 in the database?

Comment: @i regular, yea it is in database.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to attach those entities to your `DbContext`?
Even if your database have those entities, the change tracker associated with the `DbContext` must be aware of their existance if you want to `SaveChanges`.
In situations like this one, the easiest way is to manually attach them:

```
Mark mark = new Mark() { Id = 1 };
db.Marks.Attach(mark);

CarModel carModel = new CarModel() { Id = 1 };
db.CarModels.Attach(carModel);
```

Next you can associate them with your car instance:

```
car.CarModel = carModel;
car.Mark = mark;
```

And this should work because, like the doc says about `Attach`:

> **Attach is used to repopulate a context with an entity that is known to
>   already exist in the database**. `SaveChanges` will therefore not attempt
>   to insert an attached entity into the database because it is assumed
>   to already be there. Note that entities that are already in the
>   context in some other state will have their state set to Unchanged.
>   Attach is a no-op if the entity is already in the context in the
>   Unchanged state.